# How to open a URL containing a fragment (#foo) using SharedApplication and openURL on iPhone

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari

I have a URL containing a fragment part, used to indicate a certain state of the webpage.
I want to open this link in Safari on the iPhone by using something like the following:

```
NSURL* fragmentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.exampleurl.com/index.html#foo"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:fragmentURL];
```

The link is successfully opened by Safari, but the fragment part is stripped.
Has anybody got an idea on how to make Safari also use the fragment part?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "the fragment part is stripped", do you mean your web server sees a request with no fragment identifier? That's normal since the UA (browser) is supposed to strip that part.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Processing (pun intended!)